# Java runtime find out if JDK Features are available

Tags: runtime, java

Is there such a thing as a system call that tells you if you are running on top of a "naked" JRE instead of a JDK-packed? (short of ClassNotFound exceptions).
Basic question indeed, but nothing bubbles up in Google/SO.

Comment: JRE is runtime, not JDK and code always runs on JRE.

Comment: There must be a way to tell them appart, if you need to compile stuff on the fly for example.

Comment: When you have no way of knowing which one you're running in, then it shouldn't make a difference, right? What do you **actually** need to know about your environment? If you'll be able to compile classes? If a given command-line tool is available? It's similar to browser-sniffing: sniff the **feature**, not the **software that's supposed to ship that feature** (because feature-sets can change).

Comment: You can never use the JRE to **compile** Java code, just to **run it**.

Comment: If you want to know if you can *compile* code, just check if [`ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler()) returns a non-null value.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that very trick :) Thanks though.

Comment: @MonoThreaded - what is your real question? Do you want to know if you'll be able to compile code on the fly, or something else. As Joachim Sauer said, you should be looking for capabilities, and if you describe the capability you want, you will get an answer.

Comment: I want to report if the system will be able to compile code before failing.

Comment: Then you've got your answer, albeit as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following trick in order to determine the existence of the JDK:

If the return value of `javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` is `null`?
Then no compiler is available and your are running  on top of a "naked" JRE.
Otherwise, the return value will be `JavaCompiler`.

This will work on almost all of the scenarios, excepts if for some reason you include this JDK jar manually and not as part of the full JDK (on that case, it will not return null).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `JRE`(Java Run-time Environment) is Java's run time environment.

**JRE**

> Java Runtime Environment (JRE) contains JVM, libraries, and other
>   supporting files. It does not contain any development tools such as
>   compiler, debugger, etc. Actually, JVM runs the program, and it uses
>   the class libraries, and other supporting files provided in JRE. If
>   you want to run any java program, you need to have JRE installed in
>   the system.

**JDK**

> Java Developer Kit (JDK) contains tools needed to develop Java programs, along with the
>   JRE to run the programs. The tools include compiler (javac.exe),
>   Java application launcher (java.exe, jawaw.exe), Appletviewer, etc.

**You need JDK only if you want to write programs, and to compile them. For running java programs, JRE is sufficient.**

Comment: I rephrased the question for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Everything runs on the JRE, JDK refers to the set of tools that allows java development like the javac compiler, or visualvm aplication to view information about running vms. There is no such a thing like running on the JDK

If you need to compile things on the fly you start another process calling the javac. Or you use the eclipse compiler for java which is a jar file that compiles java code bytecode.